# OnMouseDown event received outside camera view port, where object is not visible

Tags: unity-game-engine, collider

1. An object has a collider 2D and is outside the camera viewport. Below the camera viewport to be exact.
2. The camera is rendering only on a portion of the screen-buffer/viewport-rect. The camera is orthographic.
3. The object has monobehaviour attached with OnMouseDown event declared in it.

[image]

Green is collider, white is camera viewport.

[image]

This is game view. pink is area being rendered by camera, it is taking touch event on highlighted red area.

When clicked just below the render area of the camera, the object receives OnMouseDown. which it should not because the object is not visible.

I have tried reproducing the issue on Editor with no success.

There is only one camera in the scene.

```cs
void OnMouseDown()
{
    Debug.Log("Clicked");
}
```

It behaves correctly on Editor, means it does not take a touch in Editor. But on Windows player (build) when touched below the drawing area (viewport rect) of the camera, the button receives the event.

Why the behaviour difference between editor and player?

It should not take touch on objects outside the viewport.

Comment: Does an object need to be visible in that viewport in order to be clicked? Afaik it is enough if it is within the display and it's collider is enabled. Maybe you could use [`OnBecameVisible`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameVisible.html) and [`OnBecameInvisible`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameInvisible.html) to simply enable and disable the collider?

Comment: One more thing I noticed is that I tried this with 2 different Unity version.:

Unity 2017
- takes touch in player
- does not take touch in editor

Unity 5.6
- does not take touch in Player
- does not take touch in Editor

Comment: @derHugo your solution is right but I wanted to know the root cause. What is the expected/correct behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to unity version 2017.4.26 fixed the issue. it is 100% reproducible in version Unity 2017.4.5.
It is an engine issue.

Possible solutions are:
1) upgrade to unity 2017.4.26f
2) as @derHugo said in above comment "Maybe you could use OnBecameVisible and OnBecameInvisible to simply enable and disable the collider?"